# javascript library that can sort table with scientific notation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the javascript class sorttable for my tables (see here: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/)

However, I have a table that uses scientific notation.  When I sort the column it looks like this...

```
9.43947E-20
9.41332E-22
9.36423E-22
9.35113E-18
9.2744E-23
9.18754E-22
9.09174
8.3981E-22
7.72743E-19
7.69538E-18
7.23656E-19
```

It is not properly sorted.  I want it to look like this...

```
9.09174
9.35113E-18
7.69538E-18
7.72743E-19
7.23656E-19
9.43947E-20
9.41332E-22
9.36423E-22
8.3981E-22
9.2744E-23
```

Is there a javascript function that can do this?  Thanks.

Comment: @Diodeus? Are you sure? See my answer.

Comment: There is a function for everything, you just have to write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above will work using my [sorTable](http://phrogz.net/JS/sorTable/) library (which happens to also use jQuery on the back currently):

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bBJBa/1/

They key is to convert the string value to numbers using something like `*1` or `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.

Comment: Yes, as is easy to test (and as you know from your answer), `parseFloat("1e-3")` will return `0.001`.

Comment: No, I was merely pointing out that `parseFloat` works as well. :)

Comment: The demo doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville No? I've edited the URL to make it more obvious how to interact with it, and default to sort. If it's still not working for you, I'd love to know the OS/browser/version.

Comment: I must not be understanding what the fiddle is supposed to do. Could you explain? I clicked "Value" and nothing happened. Then I edited the HTML to give a larger and then smaller value to one of the `<td>`'s. Nothing changed... I'm using Google Chrome v. 18.0.1025.168 m on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: @Elliot For me in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and IE9 on Windows 7 and OS X the table displays auto-sorted correctly, and clicking on "Value" toggles the sort direction.

Comment: Strange, I don't know why it's not working for me. Oh well, I'm sure it's cool. :)

Comment: At first it wasn't working but then I saw that you have to specify thead tags.  After adding those it worked perfectly for me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArrayOfNumbersAsStrings.sort(function(a,b){
    if(parseFloat(a) < parseFloat(b)) return -1;
    if(parseFloat(a) > parseFloat(b)) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Or: `a*=1; b*=1; return a<b?-1:a>b?1:0` :)

Comment: *[shudder]* Yes, or that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```javascript
numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
  return Number(a) - Number(b);
}); // => The array "numbers" is now sorted numerically ascending.
```

Comment: +1 for showing that the `sort` comparator only requires positive and negative return values, not explicitly `1` and `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You want them sorted largest to smallest-

```
   var A= [
        '9.43947E-20',
        '9.41332E-22',
        '9.36423E-22',
        '9.35113E-18',
        '9.2744E-23',
        '9.18754E-22',
        '9.09174',
        '8.3981E-22',
        '7.72743E-19',
        '7.69538E-18',
        '7.23656E-19'
    ];
    A.sort(function(a, b){
        return b-a;
    }).join('\n')

    /*  returned value: (String)
    9.09174
    9.35113E-18
    7.69538E-18
    7.72743E-19
    7.23656E-19
    9.43947E-20
    9.41332E-22
    9.36423E-22
    9.18754E-22
    8.3981E-22
    9.2744E-23
    */
```